# Proving an identity involving sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am a high school student and studying my first chapter in sets. I was proving an identity which is

$$ A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B)- (A\cap C)$$

I thought to prove this by proving each LHS and RHS subsets of each other: First, I let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A \cap (B - C)$ , that is,

$$ x \in A \cap (B - C)$$
$$\implies x \in A \; and \; x \in (B - C)$$
$$\implies x \in A \; and \; (x \in B \; and \; x \notin C) $$
$$\implies (x \in A \ and \ x \in B) \ and \ (x \in A \ and \ x \notin C) $$
$$\implies x \in (A \cap B) \ and \ x \notin (A\cap C)$$
$$\implies x \in (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$$
$$\implies A \cap (B - C) \subseteq (A \cap B)- (A\cap C) \quad \text{     ...........(i)}$$

Now, let $y$ be an arbitrary element of $(A \cap B)- (A\cap C)$. Then,

$$x \in (A \cap B)- (A\cap C)$$
$$x \in (A \cap B) \ and \ x \notin (A\cap C)$$
$$(x \in A \ and \ x \in B) \ and \ (x \notin A \ or \ x \notin C)$$

After this, I don't how to proceed further to get the desired result. When I looked out the solution given in textbook, it says, proceed just as the first step which requires that if $x \notin (A \cap B)  $, then $x \in A \ and \ x \notin C$ which is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.  Use the fact that you have and $(x \in A \ and \ x \in B) $  to split it into both $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ separately.  Then use $x\in A$ along with
$(x \notin A \ or \ x \notin C)$ to conclude that $x\notin C$.

Putting $x\in B$ together with $x\notin C$ gets you $x\in  B-C$, combined with your $x\in A$ gets you the $x\in A \cap (B-C)$ as desired

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.